# CSS - Different render in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, stylesheet

I am working on a website template and I contact you because I cannot figure out where the problem is.

If you check it on google chrome, the images (inside the `<ul></ul>` `#results`) under the search result bar (`.resultbar`) are well aligned, but on both firefox and IE it looks weird, like if there were a left margin on the first images, and so all of them are displaced.

I paste all the code here and a codepen link under it:

```
<body>
<header>
<div id="top-header">
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href='#' class='menu-link'><li>Videos</li></a>
            <a href='#' class='menu-link'><li>Categories</li></a>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

    </nav>
</div>
<div id="down-header">
<div id="form-container">
    <!--<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />-->
    <a class="search-submit-button" href="javascript:search()">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="searchtext">
        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" placeholder="Search 1000’s of videos...">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="form-filter">

    <input class="labeled-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="hd">
    <label for="hd" id="hd-checkbox">
        <span class="labeled-checkbox-unchecked">HD ONLY</span>
        <span class="labeled-checkbox-checked">HD ONLY</span>
    </label>

    <div class="lenght-filter">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="short">
        <label for="radio1">SHORT</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="long">
        <label for="radio2">LONG</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="all" checked>
        <label for="radio3">ALL VIDEOS</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<div id="content">
<div class="resultbar">
<h1>300000 results for "lol"</h1>
<!-- Sub menu dropdown -->
<ul class="order-filter">
<li>
<span>Date added</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
<ul>
  <li>Relevance</li>
  <li>Duration</li>
  <li>Date added <i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
</ul>
 </li>
</ul>
<!-- /Sub menu dropdown -->
</div>
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid" id="results">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/tcimages/pm5544.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>Felis catus</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
</div>


</body>
```

And here the css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}

a {
    color: #F4BEFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    color: #444;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/RKLjC33.png') repeat scroll #303030;
    height: 192px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #151515;
    z-index: 100;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#top-header {
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

#down-header {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    background: #28282a;
    border-top: 4px solid #151515;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#content {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 196px;
    width: 80%;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 195px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 80px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background: transparent url('http://www.eventbrite.com/custombutton?eid=2482178262') no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    #top-header {
        height: 100px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    #down-header {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    #content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
}

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
}

.ad {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#menu-icon {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(../images/menu-icon.png) no-repeat center;
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #BBB;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* font-size: 16px; */;
}

.current {
    color: #2262AD;
}

section {
    margin: 80px auto 40px;
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
/*MEDIA QUERY*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {

    header {
        /*position: absolute;*/;
    }

    #menu-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 5px solid #444;
        right: 20px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
}

/*Search bar */
/*import font awesome css icon library*/

#s {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
}

#searchtext {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #28282a;
}

a.search-submit-button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EF7896;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    color: #5e5e5e !important;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 45px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 40px;
}

#form-container {
    min-width: 290px;
    z-index: 9999;
                /* width: 100%; */;
}

#form-filter {
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #28282a;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    min-width: 290px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.lenght-filter {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.hd-filter {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#results {
    /* margin-top: 163px; */;
}

/*responsive*/

#results li {
/* padding: 0; */;
}

.cbp-rfgrid {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20%;
 /* Fallback */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 5);
    width: calc(90% / 5);
    padding: 1%;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a,
.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -10%;
    margin-top: -10%;
}

/* Flexbox is used for centering the heading */
.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: rgba(71,163,218,0.2);
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a:hover div {
    opacity: 1;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Example for media query: change number of items per row */

@media screen and (max-width: 1190px) {
    .cbp-rfgrid li {
        width: 23%;
 /* Fallback */
        width: -webkit-calc(92% / 4);
        width: calc(92% / 4);
        padding: 1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 945px) {
    .cbp-rfgrid li {
        width: 31.3333333%;
 /* Fallback */
        width: -webkit-calc(94% / 3);
        width: calc(94% / 3);
        padding: 1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .cbp-rfgrid li {
        width: 48%;
 /* Fallback */
        width: -webkit-calc(96% / 2);
        width: calc(96% / 2);
        padding: 1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .cbp-rfgrid li {
        width: 98%;
 /* Fallback */
        width: -webkit-calc(98% / 1);
        width: calc(98% / 1);
        padding: 1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 305px) {
    .cbp-rfgrid li {
        width: 98%;
        padding: 1%;
    }
}

.menu-link li {
    color: #BBB;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: larger;
}

.menu-link:hover li {
    color: #FFF;
}

.resultbar {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #333537), color-stop(100%, #1e1e1f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.resultbar h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

/*SearchBar design */

.order-filter {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
}

.order-filter li {
    font: 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #4f4f4f;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #393939 0%, #4f4f4f 97.56%, #636466 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #393939 0%, #4f4f4f 97.56%, #636466 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #393939 0%, #4f4f4f 97.56%, #636466 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #393939 0%, #4f4f4f 97.56%, #636466 100%);
    padding: 4px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 85px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.order-filter li:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.order-filter li ul {
    z-index: 10000;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0;
    width: 85px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.order-filter li ul li {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 83px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1a1a1c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #373737;
    border-left: 1px solid #373737;
    border-right: 1px solid #373737;
}

.order-filter li ul li:hover {
    color: #ee577c;
}

.order-filter li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.order-filter li i {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

/*
 * CSS Labeled Checkbox
 *
 * @author: Francisco Neves
 * @site: www.francisconeves.com
 */

/** Reset */
* { outline: none !important; }
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }

/**
 *  ==== Custom Labeled Checkboxes ====
 */
    /** Fonts */
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'open_sans_lightregular';
        src: url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.svg#open_sans_lightregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: 800;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'open_sans_semiboldregular';
        src: url('../fonts/opensans-semibold-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/opensans-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/opensans-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/opensans-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/opensans-semibold-webfont.svg#open_sans_semiboldregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    /** Freebie */
    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox + label
    {

        display: table;
        max-width: 170px;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 10px;
        background:#373737 url('../images/pagination-gradient-x.png') repeat-x;
        color: #a7a7a7;
        cursor: pointer;

        border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;


        transition: background-color 200ms;
        -moz-transition: background-color 200ms;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms;
        -o-transition: background-color 200ms;

        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox.icon + label
    {
        width: auto;
    }

        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox + label > span.labeled-checkbox-unchecked
        {
            background: url( ../images/checkbox-unchecked.png ) no-repeat left center;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox + label > span.labeled-checkbox-checked
        {
            background: url( ../images/checkbox-checked.png ) no-repeat left center;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox.icon + label > span.labeled-checkbox-unchecked
        {
            display: block;
            background-position: center;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox.icon + label > span.labeled-checkbox-checked
        {
            display: block;
            background-position: center;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox + label ::selection
    {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }

    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox + label ::-moz-selection
    {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }

    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox + label:hover
    {
        background-color: #EF7896;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox:not(:checked) + label > span.labeled-checkbox-checked
        {
            display: none;
        }

    /* When Checked */
    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox:checked + label
    {
        background: #EF7896;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox:checked + label:hover
    {
        background-color: #EF7896;
    }
        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox:checked + label > span.labeled-checkbox-unchecked
        {
            display: none;
        }

        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox:checked + label > span.labeled-checkbox-checked
        {
            display: inline;
        }

        input[type=checkbox].labeled-checkbox.icon:checked + label > span.labeled-checkbox-checked
        {
            display: block;
        }

#hd-checkbox{
float: left;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*
  Hide radio button (the round disc)
  we will use just the label to create pushbutton effect
*/
input[type=radio] {
    display:none; 
    margin:10px;
}

/*
  Change the look'n'feel of labels (which are adjacent to radiobuttons).
  Add some margin, padding to label
*/
input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-3px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#373737 url('../images/pagination-gradient-x.png') repeat-x;
    border-color: #ddd;
    color: #ffffff;
}
/*
 Change background color for label next to checked radio button
 to make it look like highlighted button
*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
   background: #EF7896;
    color: #ffffff;
}

label{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is a codepen link to so you can check: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoprg

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from the floats in `resultbar` that aren't cleared.

Easiest fix would be to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.resultbar`

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hxtpq)

```
.resultbar {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #333537), color-stop(100%, #1e1e1f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #1e1e1f 0%, #272729 97.56%, #333537 100%);
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: 5px;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```